# How would you import a SQLite table into a new database with PHP/PDO?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

How would you create an SQLite database with PHP/PDO importing one table of the database from another existing SQLite database?

This is what I thought so far in pseudo-code:

```
$existing_database = 'database1.sqlite';
try
{
  $dbhandle = new PDO('sqlite:database2.sqlite');

  $dbhandle->exec("CREATE TABLE new_table IMPORT table from $existing_database");

  $dbhandle = NULL;
  }

catch(PDOException $e)
  {
  print 'Exception : '.$e->getMessage();
  }
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with PHP/PDO actually. PDO is just an interface to run your query. Whatever query your database supports, PDO can send it all right. So you have to ask for Sqlite query, not PDO code.

Answer (score 0):

existing_database = 'database1.sqlite';

```
try
{
  $dbhandle = new PDO('sqlite:database2.sqlite');

  $dbhandle->exec("ATTACH DATABASE 'database1.sqlite' AS existing_database");

  $dbhandle->exec('CREATE TABLE table AS SELECT * FROM existing_database.table');

  $dbhandle = NULL;
  }

catch(PDOException $e)
  {
  print 'Exception : '.$e->getMessage();
  }
```